# Неверный ajax запрос к joomla

Tags: joomla, php, ajax

Возникла проблема. Пишу компонент для джумлы. В javascript пишу запрос к серверу, прописую путь к файлу (скрипт, который должен выдать данные - отдельным файлом), а он возвращает `restricted access`. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

покажите ajax запрос! если обращаетесь к контроллеру своего компонента что бы отключить шаблон допишите в запрос &format=raw; (joomla 1.5) много нюансов нужен код !

Answer (score 0):

Случайно не в этом дело: `defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');`? :)

Comment: :)) да вроде нет, в том скрипте нету такой записи))